# Update two repositories for a module

Tags: java, git, maven, pom.xml

I am a beginner in the use of Git.

I have five modules currently hosted on repositories, module1 to module5.
I would like to integrate those five repositories in a parent repository, so that it can use them during the build.
This parent module defines the 5 modules like that in the pom :

```
<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
    <module>module4</module>
    <module>module5</module>
    <module>module6</module>
</modules>
```

The idea would be to commit/push each of these modules both in their current repository and in this parent repository, in order to keep it updated. 
Is there something to be defined in the git configuration to allow this behaviour ?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of any simple way to do this directly in git. On a *nix machine, you could use a cron job to rsync and push multiple folders, but that will probably end badly. Why do you need to push in both places? I would recommend setting up a CI server like Jenkins, get it to build and deploy your modules whenever you check them in, and add them as standalone dependencies in your parent project instead of modules. What's your specific requirement?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you have separated those modules in different git repos?